# Blank page is returned with primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to use primefaces in the project I am working on. So I thought it would be a good idea to get some simple hello world program. It has worked fine, so I suppose all the libriaries I have to place in lib folder (I am using apache tomcat) working fine. Next I tried to draw some charts, to do so I looked at the examples and decided to use one, however I am getting a blank page... I tried to play with faces-config.xml however I was getting either blank page or the following message: 
Bean or property class try.ChartBean for managed bean ChartBean cannot be found

I tried play with xml files - but its no use... Can someone see any errors here!? Maybe someone had similar errors before!? Any help greatly appriciated!!!

test - web page to display charts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<h:body>
<f:view contentType="text/html">

<p:barChart id="basic" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne"  
            title="Basic Bar Chart" min="0" max="200" style="height:300px"/>  

<p:barChart id="horizontal" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="se" style="height:300px"  
            title="Horizontal Bar Chart" orientation="horizontal" min="0" max="200"/>  

<p:barChart id="stacked" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne" style="height:300px"  
            title="Stacked Bar Chart" stacked="true" barMargin="50" min="0" max="300"/>  
</f:view>

</h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" >

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>imageUpload.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>ChartBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.primefaces.examples.view.ChartBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

ChartBean.java

```
package org.primefaces.examples.view;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.primefaces.model.chart.CartesianChartModel;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartSeries;

public class ChartBean implements Serializable {

    private CartesianChartModel categoryModel;

    public ChartBean() {
        createCategoryModel();
    }

    public CartesianChartModel getCategoryModel() {
        return categoryModel;
    }

    private void createCategoryModel() {
        categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();

        ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();
        boys.setLabel("Boys");

        boys.set("2004", 120);
        boys.set("2005", 100);
        boys.set("2006", 44);
        boys.set("2007", 150);
        boys.set("2008", 25);

        ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();
        girls.setLabel("Girls");

        girls.set("2004", 52);
        girls.set("2005", 60);
        girls.set("2006", 110);
        girls.set("2007", 135);
        girls.set("2008", 120);

        categoryModel.addSeries(boys);
        categoryModel.addSeries(girls);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the correct url for the Primefaces library?   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"  That .tr at the end doesn't look right

Comment: Thanks, you right, it actually does not look right... Just removed it - does not make any difference at all...

Comment: First of all, make a basic sample like showing a `<h:outputText value="It works" />` in order to test JSF in new project. Then start adding components and see which one is causing the problems.

Comment: Agree to start simple.  You've removed the taglib declaration, and you're still attempting to use elements from the tag library (ie, the p:tagLibrary elements).  So, it looks like the Faces servlet isn't processing the xhtml files.

Answer (score 1):

Three issues I see directly.
The promefaces xml namespace is wrong.
It should be **xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"**

Now have all the dom that you make inside html held in the view.
i,e. Your view definition should be

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<f:view>
    <h:head/>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:somecomponentofyourchoice />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

**Note the head element**. For primefaces components to render properly, you should have a head placeholder.

- Use Web App 3 / JSF2.x configuration. No faces config is needed, just annotations and is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You specified a managed bean name of `ChartBean` in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<managed-bean-name>ChartBean</managed-bean-name>
```

However, you're trying to access it by a managed bean name of `chartBean`:

```html
<p:barChart ... value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}">
```

Those doesn't match. Fix the managed bean name accordingly conform standard Java conventions:

```xml
<managed-bean-name>chartBean</managed-bean-name>
```

Or, just get rid of the old fashioned JSF 1.x style of configuring managed beans; remove the `<managed-bean>` entry in `faces-config.xml` altogether and put the following annotations on the class:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ChartBean implements Serializable {
```

It'll default to the right managed bean name `chartBean` already.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the PrimeFaces XML namespace URI `http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui` is from PrimeFaces 2.x while we're already at PrimeFaces 3.x since 2 years ago. I'm not sure if this is intentional and/or if you've read the right and up to date guides/tutorials, but this may cause another problems not related to your current problem: the PrimeFaces 3.x tags wouldn't be recognized and parsed when using the old PrimeFaces 2.x XML namespace URI instead of the 3.x one `http://primefaces.org/ui`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I replaced primefaces.jar in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib and it worked. 
I guess primefaces.jar gets corrupt sometimes.